# Fabric Js - Is there a way to identify the direction of scaling

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I am working on a project in which use fabric js for custom shape rendering. I am in a need to set some values while we scale a fabric js object. But the case is while we scale in value has to be incremented and while scaling out value has to be decremented.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach an `scaling` event for each object.

```
Object.on('scaling', function(opt) {
  var shape = opt.target;
  if (!shape.oldScaleX) return;
  if (Math.abs(shape.scaleX) > Math.abs(shape.oldScale)) {
    return true; //scaling up!
  } else {
    return false; //scaling down!
  }
  shape.oldScaleX = shape.scaleX;
});
```

this will take care of it if you have oldScale defined.
to have always oldScale defined, consider add an event on canvas object added to define it.

```
Canvas.on('object:added', function(opt) {
  opt.target.oldScaleX = opt.target.scaleX;
})
```

Comment: It works, Thanks,
Just a correction 
 if (Math.abs(shape.scaleX) > Math.abs(shape.oldScaleX)) {